# Can I not authenticate from a non HTTPS site with the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Using the official Dropbox PHP SDK, I'm starting the oauth process from a local site where the redirect URI is simple HTTP

```
Invalid redirect_uri: "http://mylocalsite.local/finish": When response_type=code, only localhost URIs can start with "http://"; all others must start with "https://".
```

Does that mean that I can't use Dropbox with an HTTP site or is there a different configuration I can use?
The `response_type` is hardcoded to `code` in the SDK

Comment: Got some code we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of security, Dropbox API OAuth 2 redirect URIs can only use http:// on localhost. (Otherwise, sensitive information would be sent in the clear.)

So, you'll need to use https:// on any non-localhost redirect URI. For working locally, you can use http://, but the address will need to be localhost.

Comment: Thanks. Using this SDK, I can still use HTTP though. https://github.com/BenExile/Dropbox

Comment: It looks like that SDK uses OAuth 1, which doesn't require pre-registered redirect URIs.